# Can't import packages in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, importerror

I've seen a bunch of similar questions but somehow can't get over it.

I am on Ubuntu. It uses python2.7 by default but I needed python3. I figured out the way best was to use virtualenv. So I did. I created a virtualenv using python 3 and installed some packages.

When I run (with env turned on):

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

which does not seem correct. This is not the virtualenv python path. As a result I can't import any packages that I had installed inside of the virtualenv. Ideas?

Comment: How did you install it with python 3 and are you sure you're environment is activated?

Comment: I think it was `virtualenv -p python3 env_name`. It sure is activated. All imports work well when I open python in terminal. But it does not work when I run the code from within text editor (eg sublime text3) because the editor points to a wrong python3 path (not that one in virtuanenv)

Comment: Well of course, that is probably defined somewhere in the editor settings. Virtualenv is designed to work in the shell. Remember that virtualenv is only a wrapper for a bunch of files. Point your editors python executable to the virtualenv python.

Comment: Changing python path within my editor did it. Thanks @msvalkon. If you wish, post the solution and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a virtualenv version especially for python3:
On Ubuntu 14.04 for example use `pyvenv-3.4`.

You code example runs fine with pyvenv-3.4:

```
(python-venv) user:~/tmp/test/python-venv$ python test.py 
/home/user/tmp/test/python-venv/bin/python
```

additionally, `python --version` and `which python` both return the expected results:

```
(python-venv) user:~/tmp/test/python-venv$ which python
/home/user/tmp/test/python-venv/bin/python
(python-venv) user:~/tmp/test/python-venv$ python --version
Python 3.4.0
```

Comment: Thank you for pyvenv hint I may try it in the future! For now msvalkon's solution did the job.